# close multiple modal form window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a web-app in which a window is there, within which, on clicking a button a new window is created using "window.showModalDialog" function. On new window there is a link, on clicking a link a new window is created using "window.showModalDialog".

Now, the requirement is, on timeout in the child window, i want to close these windows that was created.

I tried using Window.close() function within the setTimeOut function but it only closes the top most window. please help me on this issue. Jquery solution is also welcome.

```
var sessionTimeout = 2;
var warningTime = 0; 
var thisWarningTimer = null; 
var TimeOutTimer = "";
var sDisconnectURL = "SMTime";

function startTimeoutTimer()
{
    sFlag="Y";
    thisWarningTimer = setInterval("popupAsk()", (sessionTimeout) * 60000);
    refreshSession();
}
function refreshSession()
{
    warningTime = 1;
    ClearTimer();
}
function startTimeOut()
{
    var TimeOutTimer = setInterval("popupAsk()", (sessionTimeout) * 60000);
}
function ClearTimer()
{
    clearInterval(TimeOutTimer);
    startTimeOut();
}
function popupAsk()
{
    alert("Session Timeout");   
    location.href="SMTime/Disconnect.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Please show your setTimeOut function code. Infact all your code

Comment: Hi Dumisani, I attach my code in my question. I use refreshSession() on mousemove event.